# Как отфильтровать определенные данные в scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, ionicframework

Есть scope:

```
$rootScope.categories = [
     {id: 1, parent_id: 0, title : 'Кафе'},
     {id: 2, parent_id: 1, title : 'Кафе.1'},
     {id: 3, parent_id: 1, title : 'Кафе.2'},
     {id: 4, parent_id: 1, title : 'Кафе.3'},
     {id: 5, parent_id: 0, title : 'Рестораны'},
     {id: 6, parent_id: 5, title : 'Рестораны.1'},
     {id: 7, parent_id: 5, title : 'Рестораны.2'},
     {id: 8, parent_id: 5, title : 'Рестораны.3'}];
```

Как выбрать значения только с parent_id = 0 ?

Делаю так, но так выводится весь scope:

```
.controller('CategoriesCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.categories = $rootScope.categories;

})
```

Затем в шаблоне:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="cat in categories" href="#">
     {{cat.title}}
</ion-item>
```

Как вывести все значения с parent_id = 0 (Кафе, Рестораны)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть много способов сделать то, что вам нужно, например:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="cat in categories" ng-if="cat.parent_id === 0" href="#">
     {{cat.title}}
</ion-item>
```

и

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="cat in categories | filter:{'parent_id': 0}:true" href="#">
     {{cat.title}}
</ion-item>
```

и

```
.controller('CategoriesCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
      $scope.categories = ($rootScope.categories || [])
                          .filter(function(category){
                             return category.parent_id === 0;
                          });

})
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло